# Random Variable Definition: Sample versus Event Space

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Forgive me if this question is banal or ill-posed. I am not trying to confuse myself and others, but am looking for clarification from more experienced people.

Recall that a random variable $X$ has been defined as,
$$
  X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}
$$
Where $\Omega$ refers to the **sample space**, which is the set of all possible **outcomes**.

However, the random variable effectively is a function which maps **events** to **reals** between $0$ and $1$.

Now, an **event** $A$, is **a** set of possible outcomes. In others words, $A \subseteq \Omega$.

Clearly, the set of all events, or **event space** is $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, since that is the set of all subsets of $\Omega$, hence its power set.

And here is my question: Since $X$ assigns events to $r \in \mathbb{R}$, in other words $A \mapsto r \in \mathbb{R}$, why isn't it defined as follows?
$$
 X:\mathcal{P}(\Omega) \to \mathbb{R}
$$

**EDIT:** I get that the experiment must give an event that conforms with the random variable, i.e., a die throw can only give $A = \{k\}$ where $k\in \{1,...,6\}=\Omega$, and never $A=\{1,2\}\in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. Clearly, I'm a bit confused, please help.

Surely I must be missing something. Thank you for the wisdom.

Comment: I do recall that in a measure-theoretic context, the event space $\mathcal{F}$ cannot always be equal to $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, for example when $\Omega$ is infinite. I am not so well-versed in measure theory, hence this question.

Comment: A random variable $X:\Omega \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ maps an **outcome** $\omega$ to a real number $X(\omega) \in \mathbb{R}$. It is incorrect to say it maps events to probabilities.

Comment: A probability measure of the form $P:Pow(\Omega) \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ indeed maps events $A$ to probabilities $P[A] \in [0,1]$.  The probability measure is already in place before we define a random variable $X:\Omega \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  With the random variable we can define the event $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \leq 1.5\}$, and the probability measure allows us to compute its probability $P[\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega)  \leq 1.5\}]$, which can be more concisely written as $P[X \leq 1.5]$.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you for clearing out the confusion.